# systemverilog arithmetic operation returns negative value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a part of code of my design as follows.

```
parameter n=256;
input [n-1:0] x;
output y;
initial begin
x = 0;
if(0 >= unsigned'(x-9))
y = 1;
end
```

My expectation is, the unsigned subtraction operation should return decimal 247 but in actual it returns -9. Is anyone having better way of coding to achieve this?
My actual requirement is, even if I subtract a smaller value from larger, the value should rollover w.r.t. parameter width (As if 0-1 should yield 255). My question may be wrong but this requirement is necessary from my project.

Answer (score 0):

247 and -9 are the same bit pattern so the arithmetic is correct. Signed vs unsigned is an interpretation of the bit pattern.

NB: 0-1 is only 255 with 8 bit numbers you have defined them as 256 bit numbers.

The following example should help clarify, We use `$signed` and `$unsigned` keywords which alters how the decimal representation is displayed but the underlying binary form does not change.

```
module tb;
  parameter n=8;
  logic [n-1:0] x;
  logic y;

 initial begin
  x = 0;

  $display("%1d", x-9);
  $display("%1b", x-9);
  $display("");
  $display("%1d", $unsigned(x-9) );
  $display("%1b", $unsigned(x-9) );
  $display("");
  $display("%1d", $signed(x-9) );
  $display("%1b", $signed(x-9) );
  $display("");

  $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Which Outputs:

```
4294967287
11111111111111111111111111110111

4294967287
11111111111111111111111111110111

-9
11111111111111111111111111110111
```

For your example you just need to use `$unsigned`:

```
module tb;
parameter n=8;
 logic [n-1:0] x;
 logic y;

 initial begin
   x = 0;
   if(0 >= $unsigned(x-9)) begin
     y = 1;
   end
   else begin
     y = 0;
   end
   $display("y: %b", y);
   $finish;
 end
 endmodule
```

Comment: Display with change in radix as unsigned, decimal gives different results, I agree. But I am stuck in a particular case.
parameter n=256;
input [n-1:0] x;
output y;
initial begin
x = 0;
if(0 >= unsigned'(x-9))
y = 1;
else 
y = 0;
end
Here I am expecting Y to be 0 as my 'if' logic is "0 is less than 0-9 i.e., 247" but getting 1. I think I am following wrong coding methods. Can you help me with this particular case?

Comment: @VinayakHiremath I have added an example showing you how to use `$unsigned` for your conditional. If this still causes issues add a comment and update answer with latest info.